# Web-based password management solutions for a digital agency

Tags: web-apps, password-manager, sharing

We are a small digital agency who are on the lookout for a cloud based (if possible) password management solution.

It is essential that we are able to have the following:

- Share passwords between the team
- Have some sort of folder structure
- Have the ability to store offline passwords with no URL - e.g server credentials etc.
- Not essential, but a slick interface would be preferred

What we have tried so far:

- [LastPass](https://lastpass.com/) 4.0: it looked very promising, however, there is a dependency to provide a URL for each password.  It assumes every account will be for a website.
- [CommonKey](https://commonkey.com/): it does not have the ability to have any folder
  structure functionality.
- [Passpack](https://www.passpack.com/): it feels very dated and clunky.

Comment: Lastpass has secure notes to store non-site related data (including server credentials).

Comment: Hey Adam, what exactly do you mean by 'have the ability to store offline passwords with no URL'?  Do you mean the ability to create a new password manager entry for a username/password without being forced to associate it with a URL?

Comment: Does it have to be hosted, or is self-hosting possible?

Comment: As you're talking about storing some "more sensitive data" offline: would a self-hosted web-based solution be acceptable, as that would catch both birds with the same stone (nothing on the cloud, but still shareable with the team)?

Comment: "So we can share passwords". I am out. No way. Nuh-uh.

Answer (score 1):

We use [KeePass](http://keepass.info/) hosted on a shared DropBox account for this exact purpose.

It is Windows-oriented but does have ports to various platforms. It is open source, free, and has a great [multi user support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KeePass#Multi-user_support).

If one user has it opened on one computer, it will lock subsequent requests to use the app on other computers in read-only mode.

Dropbox provides the cloud-based storage and auto syncing between computers.

Answer (score 0):

I recently started to use [Bitwarden](https://bitwarden.com/).
There's a free plan for personal use but also several plans for [organizations](https://bitwarden.com/#organizations) in various sizes. It provides apps for most platforms (Win, macOS, Linux; Andriod, iOS), a Web Vault and Browser Plugins for Autofill and quick saving of PWs.

- You can share PWs and secure notes in your team, even manage it with user groups.
- Create folders
- No URLs needed (a big plus is that you can add custom fields)
- The UI is alright.

Another nice thing: it's open source and you can host ist yourself.